# Convolutional Feature Encoding Methods in DCNN

Tags: deep-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, python, representation-learning

In Computer Vision, feature encoding methods are used on pre-trained DCNN to increase the feature robustness to certain conditions such as viewpoint/appearance variations [ref](https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.05105).

I was just wondering if there are already available well established methods among AI community with probably python implementations.

I found the following ones in literature but without any tutorial or code example:

1. Multi-layer pooling [ref](https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.4729)
2. Cross convolutional layer Pooling [ref](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1510.00921.pdf)
3. Holistic Pooling [ref](https://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_iccv_2015/papers/Babenko_Aggregating_Local_Deep_ICCV_2015_paper.pdf)